# Inserting Value with label using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have multiple values inside a label using innerHTML. Here's an example to better explain my issue.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="" class="mb-0" id="pointReferral"></label>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  referralCode();

  function referralCode() {
    var pointStart = "12";
    var pointEnd = "40";
    document.getElementById("pointReferral").innerHtml = "Number of Friends invited " + pointStart + "/" + pointEnd + " Friends";
  }
</script>
```

As you can see, I have two variables and I don't know how to use them so they become strings. Thank you.

Comment: You mistyped `innerHTML`. But use `textContent` instead as you are not injecting any HTML into your label.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my mistyped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a syntax error, should have used `innerHTML`, used `innerHtml`. It will do string concatenation, show will have no problem where you had doubt.

```js
referralCode();

function referralCode() {
  var pointStart = "12";
  var pointEnd = "40";
  // innerHTML
  //document.getElementById("pointReferral").innerHTML = "Number of Friends invited " + pointStart + "/" + pointEnd + " Friends";
  
  // ES6 way
  document.getElementById("pointReferral").innerHTML=`Number of Friends invited ${pointStart}/${pointEnd} Friends`;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="" class="mb-0" id="pointReferral"></label>
</div>
```

You can use ES6 and it new features. Here, I showed you a ES6 method to use variable inside a string. But, you did correctly, except for that `innerHtml`.

Comment: Thank you for the answers that are very helpful and understand my mistake that is mistype innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a `Syntax` error instead of `innerHTML`.

```
document.getElementById("pointReferral").innerHTML= "Number of Friends invited " + pointStart + "/" + pointEnd + " Friends";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert a number into string in `innerHTML` then your method is right, if you want to do mathematical calculation then remove quotes `""` from / like

```js
"Number of Friends invited " + (pointStart/pointEnd) + " Friends"
```